# const char* usage in constructor

Tags: c++

```
#include "Board.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Board::Board (const char* filename){
  filename = "puz1.txt";
  Board::fin (filename);
  if(!fin) fatal("Error in opening the file");
}
```

This is my cpp file...my hpp file is:

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "tools.hpp"
#include "square.hpp"

class Board {
private:
    SqState bd[81];
    ifstream fin;
public:
    Board(const char* );
    ostream& print(ostream& );
};

inline ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Board& b) { return b.print(out);}

#endif //Board.hpp
```

I got the below errors while I compile:

1. Error at line in cpp `filename = "puz1.txt"`.
   and error is:

   > const char* shadows a //parameter.
2. Error at line in cpp `Board::fin (filename);` 
   and error is:

   > no match call to //(std::basic_ifstream})

How do I fix them?

Comment: Why even have a parameter for the `filename` if you are going to change it or in some way not use the value?

Answer (score 2):

You can only initialize `fin` in the contructor initialization list. You also need to `#include <fstream>`. This would work:

```
Board::Board (const char* filename): fin(filename)
{
  ....
}
```

It is unclear why you are setting `filemane` to something different to what is passed in the constructor. If you want a default parameter, use

```
Board::Board (const char* filename="puz1.txt"): fin(filename) {}
```

Comment: Still I am unable to get it...I did as below:    Board::Board (const char* filename="puz1.txt"): fin(filename)   Error Msg is: no matching function for call to 'SqState::SqState()'

Comment: @user3561543 That is a completely different issue. `SqState` needs a default constructor for the initialization of `bd` to work.

Answer (score 1):

About the first error:

```
filename = "puz1.txt";
```

You are supposed to pass the `filename` as an argument, not to assign it there. If you just need to use `"puz1.txt"` then use than instead of `filename`.

The second error:

```
Board::fin (filename);
```

You can't initialize the `ifstream` object like that. Simply call `open()`.

```
fin.open("puz1.txt");
if(fin.is_open()) // you can pass additional flags as the second param
{
}
```